# is it possible to use Format String Syntax in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

this code is to plot a table like a joint probability mass function.

```
data = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
summation = np.sum(data)
arr2 = np.empty((2,3), dtype='U30')
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[0])):
        arr2[i][j] = r'$\dfrac{{{}}}{{{}}}$'.format(data[i][j] , summation)
pd.DataFrame(arr2)
```

[image]

is there params/settings in pandas DataFrame to plot this kind of table directly from `data` array?

something like this

```
pd.DataFrame(data, formatter=r'$\dfrac{{{}}}{{{}}}$'.format(data[i][j] , summation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html), e.g. (using an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)):

```
pd = pd.applymap(lambda x: fr'$\dfrac{{{x}}}{{{summation}}}$')
```

Depending on your use case you could also have a look at [Styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html).